# WiFiManager - stumbler

Tags: iphone

I tried stumbler to get ssid with iphone os 2.0 and 3.0, I am getting an error and I found that few framework is missing, can anyone tell me how to recover this?

I found a post from StackOverflow mentioning PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.Framework: how to install this, or anyone can give me the step to apply this stumbler for iphone os 3.0?

Comment: As you need just SSID only there is a standard and easy way try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20838972/730807 . Just in case you need BSSID also try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20836590/730807

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library is now located at: /System/Library/SystemConfiguration/WiFiManager.bundle/WiFiManager

So you'll need to change your libhandle to:

```
libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/WiFiManager.bundle/WiFiManager",RTLD_LAZY);
```

I should also mention that this is a private Apple framework and as such is likely to be buggy/not very usable - anything you do with it is at your own risk

Comment: how about the handle, keep remaining as before or have to modify

 open  = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211Open");
 bind  = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211BindToInterface");
 close = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211Close");
 associate = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211Associate");
 scan  = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211Scan");
    
 open(&airportHandle);
 bind(airportHandle, @"en0");

thanks