# How do I get the current access point's MAC address/BSSID?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wifi, bssid

My iPhone is connected to an access point through a WiFi connection. Does anybody now how I can retrieve this Access Point's MAC address with Objective-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [here](http://iphone-wireless.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Stumbler/MSNetworksManager.m) and then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163984/about-stumbler/1164496#1164496)

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. Is it also possible to get the BSSIDs of all available access points instead of only the one I'm currently connected to?

Comment: Thats what this will do - the NSDictionary networks contains a list of all the visible networks

Comment: I've found this post seeking for a way to get the access point MAC Address for a Wifi network. I'm a bit confused. Using this could cause that app will be rejected for app Store?

Comment: Because its using a private API it'll get rejected. I mean you can try sneak it past them...

Comment: First link is dead.

Answer (score 7):

It works for me

- Add *SystemConfiguration.framework*
- import *< SystemConfiguration/CaptiveNetwork.h>*
- use the below method

  ```
   +(NSString *)currentWifiBSSID {

          NSString *bssid = nil;
          NSArray *ifs = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
          for (NSString *ifnam in ifs) {
              NSDictionary *info = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((__bridge CFStringRef)ifnam);

              NSLog(@"info:%@",info);

              if (info[@"BSSID"]) {
                  bssid = info[@"BSSID"];
              }
          }
          return bssid;
      }
  ```

Any usage of this code won't get your app rejected by Apple.

To know more about the Captive Network API click [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: Are you aware of a way of getting the access point's IP address?

Comment: @Darren - I am not aware of it But,here is a question related to your quest.http://stackoverflow.com/q/21945498/730807

Comment: Why is no one saying how amazing this answer was?
This should be the accepted answer. It works.