# Get the BSSID of network

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, cocoa-touch

Can we get the BSSID of the access point to which my iPhone device is connected......
I am using strumbler code to get the list of all available networks ..but not able to achieve it for the network to which device is connected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the current access point's MAC address/BSSID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460540/how-do-i-get-the-current-access-points-mac-address-bssid)