# How to get mac address of access point in ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios, wireless, access-point

I want to get some uniqe information about access points. Such as MAC address and intensity. I try to do triangle with most three intensity wireless access point in objective c. I have xcode 4.3.2 and ios 5.1. How can I do this in ios.

Answer (score 1):

Look [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460540/how-do-i-get-the-current-access-points-mac-address-bssid)

Try this :

```
CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
CFDictionaryRef captiveNetWork = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0));
NSLog(@"Connected at : %@", captiveNetWork);
NSDictionary *myDictionnary = (__bridge NSDictionary *)captiveNetWork;
NSString *bssid = [myDictionnary objectForKey:@"BSSID"];
NSLog(@"BSSID : %@", bssid);
```

Comment: it crashes app with error `Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0))`

Comment: Something is null, which line exactly?

Comment: `(__bridge_transfer id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces()` returns nil