# can't get actual bssid value on MacOS

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to get BSSID of current WiFi connection on Mac OS X 10.14 but get `nil`.

The code returning `nil` is the following:

```
NSString *bssid = [[[CWWiFiClient sharedWiFiClient] interface] bssid];
```

though SSID returns valid value:

```
NSString *ssid = [[[CWWiFiClient sharedWiFiClient] interface] ssid];
```

Other solutions works for iOS, e.g. using CaptiveNetworks framework proposed here [How do I get the current access point's MAC address/BSSID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460540/how-do-i-get-the-current-access-points-mac-address-bssid), but some methods, like `CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo` - not supported for MacOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the current access point's MAC address/BSSID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460540/how-do-i-get-the-current-access-points-mac-address-bssid)

Comment: No, @CinderBiscuits, it's not a duplication because my question is about MacOS not iOS

Comment: Did you try the solution from the other question? You use the same API for both MacOS and iOS.

Comment: My problem of the proposed solution was in that `CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo` is supported only on iOS. I get BSSID executing `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I` in separate process and parsing results, but it does not looks like a good solution..

Comment: @atlascoder have you found the solution ?

Comment: @zack - yes, but not a good one a for me - I call `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport` and parse its text output

Comment: @atlascoder so how can i pass interface `CWInterface` in the process and  get `bssid` for that paticular interface , how to do that ?

Comment: No way to use CWInterface - just call `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I` as a separate process on the host and wait for its text outputs. then extract row with BSSID

Comment: @zack, sorry, I don't know how to run a process from ObjC/Swift - I use Qt, would you like that I've added this code as an answer here?

Comment: ya i would like please post as an answer how to add this mechanism.

Comment: @zack see below

Answer (score 2):

This is not the best solution, but at least it works in Qt:

```
QString getBssidOnMac() {
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "-I";
    QProcess process;
    process.start("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport", arguments);
    process.waitForFinished();
    QString outp = process.readAllStandardOutput();
    QRegExp re_bssid(".*(BSSID\\:\\s([0-9a-fA-F]{1,2}(\\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,2}){5})).*");
    if (re_bssid.indexIn(outp) !=-1) {
        return re_bssid.cap(2);
    }
    else {
        return QString();
    }
}
```

Comment: what  are files and framework do we need import too run this code in objective c project

Comment: Well, this code is for Qt that is not for inclusion to a Xcode project but rather to replace that. I suggest you to find a way to run terminal commands from ObjC - it will work in the same way

Answer (score 1):

my two cents for OSX, in case:

- Use CoreWLAN
- Add NetworkExtensions
- Call:

  ```
     let client = CWWiFiClient.shared()
      guard let interfaces : [CWInterface] = client.interfaces() else{
          return nil
      }

      // on iOS we got the first, here we should return multiple interfaces.
      var ssid: String?
      var bssid: String?
      var interfaceNameString: String?

      for interface in interfaces{

          ssid = interface.ssid()
          bssid = interface.bssid()
          interfaceNameString = interface.interfaceName
       ...
  ```

}

be careful to activate:

[image]

if on App Store for OSX, when activating Sandboxing.