# list all wi-fi name in iphone when wi-fi is OFF

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

My question is that I get list of all wi-fi SSID even my wi-fi is OFF in iphone.  I know that logically it is impossible. But it is possible in android and it work as OS level.  So, is it possible in Iphone ?

Because requirement is that when user enter wi-fi network even user wi-fi is OFF, list of wi-fi SSID are display and user can select that SSID.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot. On the iPhone, turning the Wifi off (or turning Airplane Mode on) effectively shuts your Wifi hardware down, so there's no possible way of doing that on an unjailbroken device.

Apple limits the ways in which you can access the iPhone hardware in order to protect users from fishy apps with root permissions that could potentially drain the battery or put the hardware/driver in an unstable state.

I also don't understand why on earth you would like to do this. If you really need to do this, you can keep Wifi on but disconnected from any Wifi network. Although I suspect that even then you cannot get the list of Wifi networks from an App [1] in an unjailbroken iPhone (Apple doesn't like Wifi sniffing tools either).

If I were a user of your App, I'd like to be certain that when the Wifi is off at the OS level, it's off period. I'd be summarily pissed off if you App accessed the Wifi hardware behind my back.

1. [Find available wi-fi networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317028/find-available-wi-fi-networks)

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible in iPhone, because Apple does not provide this types of feature. I am not sure but it may be possible in JB Device.

But why you need do this type of work?

There are many silly (Technically it is not valid) features that work in android such like you add/set  wrong latitude and longitude instead of your real current latitude and longitude. So, this type of feature is not valid, but Android gives you permission to apply  it.