# Check if specific network/SSID available

Tags: ios, networking

I need to find a way to have my application react differently if the device is able to see a specific network/SSID. I have the SSID baked into my application but I can not find a way to see available networks and compare their SSID.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find available wi-fi networks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317028/find-available-wi-fi-networks)

Answer (score 1):

There is the CaptiveNetwork API, which can give you the current SSID.

You can also register a set of SSID's that you want to handle authentication in your app. So it may not be exactly what your looking for.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Reachability is a network helper utility class that will do this it checks if 3G Wifi are available or not.

Comment: I am not looking if internet is available in general. I am looking if a  specific wifi network is available/in range.