# Display all avialable wifi networks in iOS

Tags: ios, networking, xcode6, wifi

I want to get all available wifi networks in my application. How can I proceed to do that. When I used the CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo class , got only connected network. But I need to display all available networks in my iPhone range.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find available wi-fi networks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317028/find-available-wi-fi-networks)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example from [here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileWiFi.framework).
Keep in mind that your app will get rejected if you want to push your app to the app store. You can't retreive the list of all in a way it will be accepted on apple store.

```
#include <MobileWiFi.h>

static WiFiManagerRef _manager;
static void scan_callback(WiFiDeviceClientRef device, CFArrayRef results, CFErrorRef error, void *token);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    _manager = WiFiManagerClientCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);

    CFArrayRef devices = WiFiManagerClientCopyDevices(_manager);
    if (!devices) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't get WiFi devices. Bailing.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    WiFiDeviceClientRef client = (WiFiDeviceClientRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(devices, 0);

    WiFiManagerClientScheduleWithRunLoop(_manager, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    WiFiDeviceClientScanAsync(client, (CFDictionaryRef)[NSDictionary dictionary], scan_callback, 0);

    CFRelease(devices);

    CFRunLoopRun();

        return 0;
}

static void scan_callback(WiFiDeviceClientRef device, CFArrayRef results, CFErrorRef error, void *token)
{
    NSLog(@"Finished scanning! networks: %@", results);

    WiFiManagerClientUnscheduleFromRunLoop(_manager);
    CFRelease(_manager);

    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}
```