# How can I get a list of Wi-Fi nearby? This list includes the information about Wi-Fi

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to get the information about Wi-Fi nearby to show in a tableView. How can I get the Wi-Fi information?

I heard that the Apple provides some limited interface about Wi-Fi, is it true? How can I get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find available wi-fi networks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317028/find-available-wi-fi-networks)

Answer (score 1):

you can easily get all the information about the current connected Wi-Fi network by using `CNCopySupportedInterfaces` and `CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo` of CaptiveNetwork : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/index.html

Comment: Maybe I have not described the problem clearly. I mean that  Wi-fi is avaible to connect rather than connected. I want to show people which wifi can be connected