# How to get a list of available wifi networks within iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, networking, wifi, channel

I have used apple80211 framework to get list of available wifi networks within my iPhone app, but i did not get any response using that frame work. I had also used stumbler example for reference, but there is no success. Can any one help me out to solve this issue ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706134/cncopysupportedinterfaces-gives-list-of-all-configured-wifi-interfaces-informati/14706276#14706276

Comment: Thanks @Rajneesh071 for your quick response, but i have already tried that stumbler library and its not displaying any result.

Comment: sorry buddy but i did not implemented stumbler..

Comment: This is only possible using a private framework.