# iOS Reachability SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback not call back when switch form wifi to anthor wifi

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, networking, reachability

I want get a call when network is change of iPhone.

I Use Reachability.m of Apple guide like this:

xxx.m

```
struct sockaddr_in zeroAddress;
bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress));
zeroAddress.sin_len = sizeof(zeroAddress);
zeroAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
Reachability = [self reachabilityWithAddress: (const struct sockaddr *) &zeroAddress]
```

Reachability.m

```
BOOL returnValue = NO;
SCNetworkReachabilityContext context = {0, (__bridge void *)(self), NULL, NULL, NULL};
if (SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(_reachabilityRef, ReachabilityCallback, &context))
{
    if (SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(_reachabilityRef, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode))
    {
        returnValue = YES;
    }
}
return returnValue;
```

xxx.m

```
ReachabilityCallback {
    //do something when network change
}
```

I test change mobile(4G) to wifi1

recives call like

```
Status4G
StatusNone
StatusWifi1
```

When change form wifi1 to wifi2

```
StatusWifi1
StatusNone
StatusWifi2
```

However, sometimes, when wifi changes very fast and did not change to `StatusNone`, I did not get callback when i change wifi1 to wifi2 or the other way round.

What i want get is

```
StatusWifi1
StatusWifi2
```

`-------------------------UPDATE----------------------------`

Thanks @Hitesh Surani, now my question is sometimes on some devices, i did not received `disconnect state` , I try to use

```
[self reachabilityWithAddress: @"www.google.com"]
```

Replace

```
[self reachabilityWithAddress: (const struct sockaddr *) &zeroAddress]
```

Now, I can received call back when wifi is change even it did not  into `disconnect state`, but i still didn't known why, here is the state change:

```
//wifi1:
1 kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable

//wifi1 -> wifi2
2 kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable | kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsTransientConnection
3 kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable
```

when change wifi, there is tmp state `kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable | kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsTransientConnection`, that's why i can detect wifi changes, but what does `kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsTransientConnection` mean? i read the doc of Apple, still be confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for asking great qestion.

Mainly `Reachability` class is use for tracking of internet connectivity changes. There is no provsion for detect wifi changed notification. So in one word `Reachability` class not provide this type of funtionality. If you want to achieved your requirement then below customisation required.

You can achived wifi changed notification as below.

- When your wifi connection changed or switch to any other network then you have received disconnect state for fraction of second. So `reachabilityChanged` method is called.
- By using below code, You can get wifi information such as BSSID,SSID(Name) and SSID data. Just store wifi info into local.
- When network changed then you can check new wifi information is matched with previos one or not. If not then user connect with new wifi.

Put below code into `reachabilityChanged` method.

```
import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork

 func printCurrentWifiInfo() {
            if let interface = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() {
                for i in 0..<CFArrayGetCount(interface) {
                    let interfaceName: UnsafeRawPointer = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(interface, i)
                    let rec = unsafeBitCast(interfaceName, to: AnyObject.self)
                    if let unsafeInterfaceData = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo("\(rec)" as CFString), let interfaceData = unsafeInterfaceData as? [String : AnyObject] {
                        // connected wifi
                        print("BSSID: \(String(describing: interfaceData["BSSID"])), SSID: \(String(describing: interfaceData["SSID"])), SSIDDATA: \(String(describing: interfaceData["SSIDDATA"]))")
                    } else {
                        //Wifi is not connected
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Update:**

Apple provide `com.apple.system.config.network_change` to listen wifi changes notification. Basically it is part of `Core Foundation` framework. I am sure it will work for you.

Please add below code to listen wifi changes.

```
 let notificationName = "com.apple.system.config.network_change"


    func onNetworkChange(_ name : String) {
        if (name == notificationName) {
            // Do your stuff
            print("Network was changed")
        }
    }

    func registerObserver() {
        let observer = UnsafeRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
        CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), observer,
                                        { (nc, observer, name, _, _) -> Swift.Void in
                                            if let observer = observer, let name = name {
                                                let instance = Unmanaged<Reachability>.fromOpaque(observer).takeUnretainedValue()
                                                instance.onNetworkChange(name.rawValue as String)
                                            } },
                                        notificationName as CFString, nil, .deliverImmediately)
    }


    func removeObserver() {
        let observer = UnsafeRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
        CFNotificationCenterRemoveObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), observer, nil, nil)
    }
```

**Register observer on init and remove on deinit.**
Find reference from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876733/iphone-notification-when-wifi-network-changes).

Comment: Thanks!, but my new question is sometimes on some devices, i did not received ```disconnect state ```, i update my question describe.

Comment: NO, `"com.apple.system.config.network_change"` not work, it never callback when network change