# IOS get list of wifi networks available

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have simple question but i dont know how to implement this. I need to create an app that can get list of available wifi networks and when user click on some network iphone have to connect to this network. Can i do this? I want to publish app to the app store. I dont want to use private api. I knew that application osminoWifi pubblished on the appstore and do this. So, what frameworks and technologies I can use for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone get SSID without private library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library)

Comment: but this example is only for currenlty connected networks. Not for all available in range

Comment: NSDictionary *wifiDetails() {
    CFArrayRef interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
    CFDictionaryRef captiveNtwrkDict = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(interfaces, 0));
    NSDictionary *dict = ( __bridge_transfer NSDictionary*) captiveNtwrkDict;
    CFRelease(interfaces);
    return dict;
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone get a list of all SSIDs without private library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684341/iphone-get-a-list-of-all-ssids-without-private-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with abilities of the system, but you can't publish it on the appstore because it is private api.

Comment: what is names frameworks you use get list wifi ? I need it

Comment: How do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes you can get that info. Take a look at this project for example: https://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/

However, according to AppStore terms and conditions you are only allowed to get the SSID of the network you are currently connected to but your are not allowed to publish an app that uses private libraries. Take a look at this issue [How do I use CaptiveNetwork to get the current WiFi Hotspot Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712535/how-do-i-use-captivenetwork-to-get-the-current-wifi-hotspot-name)

Comment: I think you mean "but you're **not** allowed".

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of **private library (Apple80211)** it will not provide you other reachable wifi list or other info.

You can refer to: [How do I use CaptiveNetwork to get the current WiFi Hotspot Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712535/how-do-i-use-captivenetwork-to-get-the-current-wifi-hotspot-name) for more information.