# iOS How can I get wifi list around my phone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sockets, wifi

In my project, I need get list all near by WiFi in range,
I have already done lots of research but didn't get any solution, Please any one help me for same ?

thanks very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOS get list of wifi networks available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785530/ios-get-list-of-wifi-networks-available)

Comment: You can only get the current connected WIFI information.

Comment: use captivenetwork, or you may refer to this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555640/how-to-get-wifi-ssid-in-ios9-after-captivenetwork-is-deprecated-and-calls-for-wi

Answer (score 0):

By this way you can get all near by your phone

From iOS >= 4.1 it's possible to obtain SSID of wireless network that device is currenctly connected to.

For this you'd use function [CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo](https://developer.apple.com/reference/systemconfiguration#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009770-CH101-SW4)

Details on implemenation are available on SO: [iPhone get SSID without private library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library/5198968#5198968)

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of private library (Apple80211) it will not provide you other reachable wifi list or other info but if you want devices near by you You can use **multipeer connectivity**.