# Display Ranged Wifi

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, wifi

I want to display all the ranged wifi-Network in my iOS App. For this I am using the following code:

```
NSArray *interFaceNames = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
for (NSString *name in interFaceNames)
{
    NSDictionary *info = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((__bridge CFStringRef)name);
    NSLog(@"%@",info);
    NSLog(@"wifi info: bssid: %@, ssid:%@, ssidData: %@", info[@"BSSID"], info[@"SSID"],info[@"SSIDDATA"]);
}
```

But this is only giving me the connected wifi-network information.
How can I display all ranged Wifi-Network?

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317028/find-available-wi-fi-networks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOS get list of wifi networks available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785530/ios-get-list-of-wifi-networks-available)

Comment: I don't want to use jailbreak devices.
Is it compulsory to use private API ?